# Minimum install of Shibboleth on IIS, when Deamon is on Separate Computer

Tags: iis, shibboleth

I have a Shibboleth service provider (SP) served by a web farm with no outbound internet access (for security reasons). The web farm forwards authentication requests to the shibboleth daemon running on a computer that does have outbound internet.

Because of this separation, I'd like to minimize the installation on each box in the web farm. I have the following questions:

1. Is it possible to xcopy-deploy Shibboleth to the web farm, rather than using the installer? If so, what are the minimum files in addition to the isapi_shib.dll?
2. If using the installer on each server in the web farm is necessary, what folders/files can be removed post-installation?  (For instance, I see I can disable the "Shibboleth 2 Daemon" service...)

And by-the-way I am using using http://www.testshib.org for integration testing.